# How to retrieve value from cache?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, caching

I'm using [node-cache-manager](https://github.com/BryanDonovan/node-cache-manager) for managing the Node.js cache.

I've successfully added an item to the cache:

```
import cacheManager from 'cache-manager';

const memoryCache = cacheManager.caching({store: 'memory', max: 100, ttl: 3600/*seconds*/});

memoryCache.set('testItem', { 'key': 'testValue'}, {ttl: 36000}, (err) => {
      if (err) { throw err; }
});
```

But when I want to retrieve an item from the cache it responds with `Result: [Object Object]`

This is the code:

```
let cacheResult = await memoryCache.get('testItem');

console.log('Result: ' + { cacheResult });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aloha !

You have defined the variable as a JSON OBJECT and therefore Javascript considers it as an Object [Object Object].

To avoid this, you have to turn JSON Object into string
You have to do:

```
memoryCache.set('testItem', JSON.stringify({ 'key': 'testValue'}), {ttl: 36000}, (err) => {
      if (err) { throw err; }
});
```

And when you want to retrieve the content of the variable

```
let cacheResult = await JSON.parse(memoryCache.get('testItem'), true);
```

Live Exemple:

```js
var json = JSON.stringify({"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"});
var obj = JSON.parse(json, true);


console.log(obj);
console.log('Name of user: ' + obj.name)
```